# RegEx question for password strength validation

Tags: regex, passwords

I'm looking for a single regular expression for our password requirements. Passwords:

- Must be at least 8 characters
- Cannot contain spaces
- Contain both lowercase and UPPERCASE characters
- Contain at least one numeric digit
- Contain at least one special character (i.e. any character not `0-9,a-z,A-Z`)

Comment: This is an awful use of regular expressions.  It's so simple to do manually.  I'd advise against using regex for this.

Comment: I see a combinatorial explosion...

Comment: The rewuirement of it being in a single expression makes it complex and very hard to read for a human that has to maintain it. I suggest splitting it in different tests to make it more maintainable. You also forgot to mention what regexp engine you are using, since there are differences with what you could do. Depending on where the test is done, it could be of interest to give the user feedback of why the password failed.

Comment: Relevant - http://thedailywtf.com/Articles/Security-by-PostIt.aspx

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Idea and most of the work taken from http://www.zorched.net/2009/05/08/password-strength-validation-with-regular-expressions/

```
^\S*(?=\S{8,})(?=\S*[a-z])(?=\S*[A-Z])(?=\S*[\d])(?=\S*[\W])\S*$
```

I used the basic answer at the bottom of his post, but replaced all the dots with `\S` to rule out space characters, and moved around some of the assertions.

Comment: Almost +1. The referenced article is a good one, but it erroneously suggests having the `.*` dot-star at the beginning of the expression (this is not needed because the dot-star at the end will match the string). Although it does no harm for this specific problem (your answer is correct and works ok), it will fail if there is an upper limit on password length. If the length requirement is from 8 to 12 chars, then a correct expression would be: `^(?=.{8,12}$)(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*\d)(?=.*\W)\S*$` (Note also that there is no need for the `\S` in the lookaheads.) Otherwise good answer.

Answer (score 8):

It'll probably be easier to code the logic. Regex is used for matching patterns. Passwords tend to be somewhat random strings, so the problem doesn't lend itself easily to be solved by a regex. It's possible but will be cryptic to read and hard to maintain.