# Regex for Password validation in Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex, passwords

Regex Password complexity requires that `any three` of the following four characteristics must be applied when creating or changing a password.

- Alpha characters - at least 1 upper case alpha character
- Alpha characters - at least 1 lower case alpha character
- Numeric characters - at least 1 numeric character
- Special characters - at least 1 special character

I am trying with the following code, but its not working for `special characters`

```
(?=^.{6,}$)((?=.*\d)(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*[a-z])|(?=.*\d)(?=.*[^A-Za-z0-9])(?=.*[a-z])|(?=.*[^A-Za-z0-9])(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*[a-z])|(?=.*\d)(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*[^A-Za-z0-9]))^.*
```

I want my regex to be validated against the following 4 cases

Match cases

- P@ssword
- Password1
- p@ssword1
- p@12345

Comment: possible duplicate of [RegEx question for password strength validation](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5834251/regex-question-for-password-strength-validation)

Answer (score 10):

I think that a regex you can use is:

```
(?=^.{6,}$)(?=.*[0-9])(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[^A-Za-z0-9]).*
```

I'm not sure why you have so many or operators in your regex but this one matches if:

- `(?=^.{6,}$)` - String is > 5 chars
- `(?=.*[0-9])` - Contains a digit
- `(?=.*[A-Z])` - Contains an uppercase letter
- `(?=.*[a-z])` - Contains a lowercase letter
- `(?=.*[^A-Za-z0-9])` - A character not being alphanumeric.

[image: Regular expression image]

Comment: But i need any one of the three options, not all the 4.

Comment: @sivanv Oh, but isn't your regex working? See [this](http://www.regex101.com/r/yR1dZ8). And you can change the password one at a time to check the other ones.

Answer (score 7):

I think a single regex will be messy in this case. You can easily do something like

```
var count = 0;

count += /[a-z]/.test(password) ? 1 : 0;
count += /[A-Z]/.test(password) ? 1 : 0;
count += /\d/.test(password) ? 1 : 0;
count += /[@]/.test(password) ? 1 : 0;

if(count > 2) {
    alert('valid')
}
```

Comment: Can I do it with help of regex, thats the requirement. :(
I already achieved it using the above way, but need it in plain Regex.

Comment: This is regex, but multiple of them.

Comment: @sivanv you must also learn, that not always the solution is hammer, even if the problem at the beginning looks like a nail

Comment: a single regex here will be too messy and a hell to maintain later

Comment: I think you could simplify a bit: `count += +/[a-z]/.test(password)` same with the others right? Or simply: `[/[a-z]/,/[A-Z]/,/\d/,/\W/].filter(function(t){ return t.test(pass); }).length > 2`

Answer (score 2):

Use this Regex :

(?=^.{6,10}$)(?=.*\d)(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*[!@#$%^&*()_+}{":;'?/>.<,])(?!.*\s).*$**

Comment: not working even the fiddle, could you check again?, even the / is not escaped how would this even work ?

Answer (score 0):

I think you would need this for all special characters too : [updated to reject space]

```
    $(document).ready(function(){
    $('input').change(function(){
    var count = 0;
    var pass = $(this).val();
        count += /[a-z]/.test(pass) ? 1 : 0;
        count += /[A-Z]/.test(pass) ? 1 : 0;
        count += /\d/.test(pass) ? 1 : 0;
        count += /[^\w\d\s]/.test(pass) ? 1 : 0;
        (count>2 & !/[\s]+/.test(pass)) ? $(this).css('background-color','lime'):$(this).css('background-color','orange');
    });

});
```

and the fiddle : [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/CME64/6upQc/3/)

Answer (score 0):

```
var pattern = new RegExp(/^(?=.*\d)(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*[!@#$%^&*()_+\-=\[\]{};':"\\|,.<>\/?]).{6,}$/);

    if(pattern.test(value)){
         return true;
    } else {
         return false;
    }
```

Its working fine with special character also.

Answer (score 0):

### Non English UTF-8

None of the solutions given allow international letters, i.e. éÉöÖæÆáÁ, but mainly focus on the english `ASCII` alphabet.

The following regEx uses unicode, UTF-8, to recognise upper and lower case and thus, allow international characters:

```
// Match uppercase, lowercase, digit or #$!%*?& and make sure the length is 6 to 36 in length  
const pwdFilter = /^(?=.*\p{Ll})(?=.*\p{Lu})(?=.*[\d|@#$!%*?&])[\p{L}\d@#$!%*?&]{6,36}$/gu

if (!pwdFilter.test(pwd)) {
    // Show error that password has to be adjusted to match criteria
}
```

The regEx:

`/^(?=.*\p{Ll})(?=.*\p{Lu})(?=.*[\d|@#$!%*?&])[\p{L}\d@#$!%*?&]{6,36}$/gmu`

checks if an uppercase, lowercase, digit or @#$!%*?& are used in the password. It also limits the length to be 6 minimum and maximum 36 (note that emojis, ‍, count as more than one character in the length).
The `u` in the end, is for using UTF-8.

Answer (score -1):

To match for special simply list down all the special characters there are in a lookahead. See code below.

```
const pattern1 = /(?=\D)/; // non-digit character match
const pattern2 = /(?=.*[~`!@#$%^&*()--+={}\[\]|\\:;"'<>,.?/_₹])/; // at least one special char exists
```

Alternatively, assumingly, as your regex pattern already search for digits and alphabets such as in pattern 3, the only things not matching is non-digits, which are your special characters. Hence you can find match for non-digits characters too! Like in pattern 4.

```
  const pattern3 =
    /^(?=.*\d)(?=.*[~`!@#$%^&*()--+={}\[\]|\\:;"'<>,.?/_₹])(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z]).{5,10}$/;
  const pattern4 =
    /^(?=.*\d)(?=.*\D)(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z]).{5,10}$/;
```

For detailed explanation of the syntax or lookahead, you may read up the article below.

https://medium.com/p/19fc2b2a299c

Comment: Please add some more explanation to your answer such that others can learn from it. Also, share all explanation **in your answer** instead of posting links to external ressources

Comment: Thanks for the feedback, I have reviewed my answer