# How to syntactically use pattern in javascript with match method?

Tags: javascript, html

I aim at using specific pattern to check user inputs in a form and to be honest I am a beginner in javascript and not used to javascript syntax since I recently realised I would need it for my code.
More specifically my issue is the use of patterns. I went on regexr.com that gives patterns code and make you able to create your own. On there I took already existing ones for passwords (for the password it's at least 8 characters 1 uppercase 1 lowercase and 1 number) and emails. And on regexr.com the Password Rockyh12 for example match the pattern but when I add it to my website, it says it doesn't meet the password requirements. I think it is my way of putting the patterns in javascript the problem

`if(!password.value.match(pattern="^(?=.*\d)(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*[a-zA-Z]).{8,}$)"))`

The html code for the site

```
<form>
    <div class="tab tab-1 active"><h3 class="infos">Credentials</h3>
        <p>
            <label ">Email address&nbsp;<span class="required" >*</span></label>
            <input type="text" autocomplete="email" name="email" id="reg_email" value="" required />
        <div id="email_validation" style="color: red;></div>
        </p>



        
            <p>
                <label for="reg_password">Password&nbsp;<span class="required">*</span></label>
                <input type="text" name="password" id="reg_password" autocomplete="new-password" required />
                <div id="password_validation" style="color: red;"></div>
            </p>
                <br>
            
        
        

    <div class="next-0 next">
        <button type="button" name="next_1">Next</button>
    </div>
    <div class=""></div>

    </div>
</form>
```

and the javascript is here:

```
//--------EMAIL CHECK--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

const email = document.querySelector('input[name="email"]');
    var emailValidation = document.getElementById('email_validation');

    email.addEventListener("focus", (event) => {


         if(!email.value.match(/^[a-zA-Z0-9.!#$%&'*+/=?^_`{|}~-]+@[a-zA-Z0-9-]+(?:\.[a-zA-Z0-9-]+)*$/)){
           emailValidation.innerHTML="Please enter a valid email address";
           return false;
        }

        else{
            return true;
        }
});

email.addEventListener("keyup", (event) => {
    
    if(!email.value.match(/^[a-zA-Z0-9.!#$%&'*+/=?^_`{|}~-]+@[a-zA-Z0-9-]+(?:\.[a-zA-Z0-9-]+)*$/)){
      emailValidation.innerHTML="Please enter a valid email address";
      return false;
   }else {
    emaildValidation.innerHTML="";
    event.target.style.borderColor = "green";
       return true;
   }
});
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------






// ------PASSWORD CHECK-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    const password = document.querySelector('input[name="password"]');
    var passwordValidation = document.getElementById('password_validation');

    password.addEventListener("focus", (event) => {
    
         if(!password.value.match(pattern="^(?=.*\d)(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*[a-zA-Z]).{8,}$)")){
           passwordValidation.innerHTML="Password must be at least 8 character and contain 1 uppercase,1 lowercase and 1 number";
           return false;
        }

        else{
            return true;
        }
});

password.addEventListener("keyup", (event) => {
    
    if(!password.value.match(pattern="^(?=.*\d)(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*[a-zA-Z]).{8,}$")){
      passwordValidation.innerHTML="Password must be at least 8 character and contain 1 uppercase,1 lowercase and 1 number";
      return false;
   }else {
    passwordValidation.innerHTML="";
    event.target.style.borderColor = "green";
       return true;
   }
});
//-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

I have tried deleting the brackets around the pattern code and "pattern" leaving it like this

`if(!password.value.match(^(?=.*\d)(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*[a-zA-Z]).{8,}$))`

still I don't know what pattern it has been set to but it still don't work.

Comment: `/^(?=.*\d)(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*[a-zA-Z]).{8,}$)/.test(password.value)`

Comment: You're doing it correctly on your `email.value.match` method. Replicate that. I'm not sure where you're getting `pattern=""` from, but I've never seen that. Docs for your method: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/match

Comment: Also, `String.prototype.match()` returns an array of the results. If you don't plan to do anything with those results, then you're better off using `RegExp.prototype.test()`, which returns boolean.

Comment: `pattern=` is something you can use as an HTML attribute to make the browser do validation automatically, instead of writing your own JavaScript. You don't put it in the JavaScript.

Comment: @Josh Thank you so much. It worked well since I changed

Comment: @Unmitigated I tried this one but with no success. Am I supposed to use it as a boolean for a if?

Comment: @Barmar Yes I now realize it haha. Thank you

Comment: @JediaelZongo Yes, it returns a boolean.

Comment: It should also go without saying that client-side validation can easily be bypassed in the browser. It's a good first step in the process, but user-input validation can only be truly enforced on the backend.

Comment: @Josh sorry for the late reply. Been so busy. Yes, I plan on adding an email verification process after a user just signed up

Answer (score 0):

Looks like the pattern that you are trying to use is from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17102946/regex-for-password-validation-in-javascript)

You can use it like so:

```js
const check = (str) => {
  if(str.match(/^(?=^.{8,}$)(?=.*[0-9])(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[^A-Za-z0-9]).*$/)) {
    console.log(str + ' valid');
  } else {
    console.log(str + ' invalid');
  }
}

check('abcdABCD123!');  // valid
check('abcdABCD123');   // invalid - no symbols
check('abcAB');         // invalid - too short
check('ABCDEFG1!');     // invalid - no lowercase
check('abcdefg1!');     // invalid - no uppercase
check('abcdefgA!');     // invalid - no digits
```

Please let me know if this helps.